# Show image in JQuery ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a script with JQuery ui autocomplete that works perfectly. There is a search process that shows user firsname and lastname. But in my databse, there is also users' pic and I want to display it in the suggestion with the fristname and lastname.

( in the database, pic contains the image url)

The script:

```js
$(function() {    
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: "autocomplete.php",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var url = ui.item.id;
            if(url != '') {
                location.href = '...' + url;
            }
        },   
        html: true,           
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);      
        }
    });     
});
```

**autocomplete.php**

```html
<?php     
if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) ) {
 exit;
}
 
$mysqli = new MySQLi($DB_host,$DB_login,$DB_pass,$DB_select);
     
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term'])); 
$term = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $term);
 
$a_json = array();
$a_json_row = array();
 
$a_json_invalid = array(array("id" => "#", "value" => $term, "label" => "Only letters and digits are permitted..."));
$json_invalid = json_encode($a_json_invalid);
 
if(preg_match("/[^\040\pL\pN_-]/u", $term)) {
  print $json_invalid;
  exit;
}

if ($data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE '%$term%' OR lastname LIKE '%$term%' ORDER BY firstname , lastname")) {
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
  $firstname = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['firstname']));
  $lastname = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['lastname']));
  $id= htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id']));
  $pic= htmlentities(stripslashes($row['pic']));
  $a_json_row["id"] = $id;
  $a_json_row["value"] = $firstname.' '.$lastname;
  $a_json_row["label"] = $firstname.' '.$lastname;
  array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
 }
}
 
/* jQuery wants JSON data */
echo json_encode($a_json);
flush();
 ?>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just have to have an `<img>` element ready to receive the img URL...
Then on select, pass the URL to the `src` attribute.

In the demo below, I simulated your json response....
Try with "*John Doe*" or "*System Admin*".

```js
$(function() {
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: //"autocomplete.php",
    [
      {
       id:"John Doe",
       value:"John Doe",
       label:"John Doe",
       img:"http://images.maskworld.com/is/image/maskworld/bigview/john-doe-foam-latex-mask--mw-117345-1.jpg"
      },
      {
       id:"System Admin",
       value:"system Admin",
       label:"system Admin",
       img:"http://www.ericom.com/imgs/braftonArticles/3-things-every-system-admin-should-know-about-virtualization_16001411_800906167_0_14057272_500.jpg"
      }
    ],
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      /*
      var url = ui.item.id;
      if(url != '') {
        location.href = '...' + url;
      }
      */
      var img = ui.item.img;
      $("#pic").attr("src",img);
    },
    html: true, 
    open: function(event, ui) {
       $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
img{
  max-height:350px;
  max-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search"><br>
<img id="pic">
```

---

**EDIT**

Maybe you wish to have the image in the dropdown...
I found this in [jQuery-UI documentation](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data).

```js
$(function() {

      $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: //"autocomplete.php",
        [
          {id:"John Doe",
           value:"John Doe",
           label:"John Doe",
           img:"http://images.maskworld.com/is/image/maskworld/bigview/john-doe-foam-latex-mask--mw-117345-1.jpg"},
          {id:"system Admin",
           value:"system Admin",
           label:"system Admin",
           img:"http://www.ericom.com/imgs/braftonArticles/3-things-every-system-admin-should-know-about-virtualization_16001411_800906167_0_14057272_500.jpg"}
        ],
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui) {
          /*
          var url = ui.item.id;
          if(url != '') {
            location.href = '...' + url;
          }
          */
        },
        html: true, 
        open: function(event, ui) {
          $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);

        }
      })
        .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li><div><img src='"+item.img+"'><span>"+item.value+"</span></div></li>" ).appendTo( ul );
      };

    });
```

```css
.ui-menu img{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
.ui-menu li span{
  font-size:2em;
  padding:0 0 10px 10px;
  margin:0 0 10px 0 !important;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search"><br>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to take the pic from the data base. Each user have a different profile picture. So I want in the suggestion to display the profile pic, then the firstname and lastname.

Comment: My example takes the `img` source information from the json requested by autocomplete.... So from your database.

Comment: So should I do something like that $a_json_row["img"] = $pic; in autocomplete.php ?

Comment: yes... You have to send the URL from the PHP side. And I found something you might like....

Answer (score 5):

You can use [_renderItem( ul, item )](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem):

```js
$("#search").autocomplete({
    source: [
        {
            value: "aaa",
            label: "aaa",
            desc: "aaa",
            icon: "https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=aaa"
        },
        {
            value: "bbb",
            label: "bbb",
            desc: "bbb",
            icon: "https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=bbb"
        },
        {
            value: "ccc",
            label: "ccc",
            desc: "ccc",
            icon: "https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=ccc"
        }
    ],
    minLength: 0,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    }
});
$("#search").data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $('<li/>', {'data-value': item.label}).append($('<a/>', {href: "#"})
            .append($('<img/>', {src: item.icon, alt: item.label})).append(item.label))
            .appendTo(ul);
};
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="search">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to take the pic from the data base. Each user have a different profile picture. So I want in the suggestion to display the profile pic, then the firstname and lastname.

Comment: The php file is autocomplete.php.