# JQuery Autocomplete UI selected picture

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete

How can I replace the text field's value with the value of the selected item + picture.

> select: function (event, ui) {
> ui.item.value = "path to picture" // here!!! }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show image in JQuery ui autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662200/show-image-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

Comment: I want to display the picture in the suggestion and also in input form

Comment: So, I would like to display the picture in the suggestion and also in input form